# Python white space in this program

Tags: python, whitespace, removing-whitespace

```
#/usr/bin/python2.4 -tt

import sys

def mult_table(x,y):
  for i in range(1,y+1):
    for n in range(1,x+1):
      if n == 1:
        print i*n,
      elif n == x:
        print repr(i*n).rjust(3)
      else:
        print repr(i*n).rjust(3),

mult_table(12,3)
sys.exit(0)
```

I submitted this short program to [CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/). Its only job is to make a multiplication table. The problem is that it should not have any trailing whitespace and when I submitted it the last line has a space after the 36. I tested myself, and I don't have this problem. What is going on?

Comment: not sure what you want. Could you clarify?

Comment: "whitespace" is usually used to include both spaces and newlines (and tabs, etc).  So if the instructions say "no trailing whitespace", then they may not want a newline after the last line.  So you could try changing `n==x` to `n==x and i!=y` and see if that makes it happy.

Comment: @karlcow I do not understand why there is white space in the last line of my multiplication table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code adds a space for `mult_table(1,1)` not for `mult_table(12,3)`.

So you need to fix your `if n == 1` case (to also check `n == x`, as you do later in the code).

I would do this a bit differently, so that the heart of `mult_table` is something like:

```
      if n == 1:
        print i*n,
      else:
        print repr(i*n).rjust(3),
```

And then just `print` your newline in the outer for loop.

Take-home: Test your boundary conditions! :-)

Comment: Erm. I think you accepted the wrong answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945276/python-white-space/11945488#11951544 . Thanks though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In that the newline itself is whitespace, your program by design has trailing whitespace.  If you want to make a special case, you can bar the end of the table from writing a newline.

When I tested your program, I did not see a space (ASCII 0x20) after the last value:

```
$ ~/src/test/x.py | xxd
0000000: 3120 2020 3220 2020 3320 2020 3420 2020  1   2   3   4
0000010: 3520 2020 3620 2020 3720 2020 3820 2020  5   6   7   8
0000020: 3920 2031 3020 2031 3120 2031 320a 3220  9  10  11  12.2
0000030: 2020 3420 2020 3620 2020 3820 2031 3020    4   6   8  10
0000040: 2031 3220 2031 3420 2031 3620 2031 3820   12  14  16  18
0000050: 2032 3020 2032 3220 2032 340a 3320 2020   20  22  24.3
0000060: 3620 2020 3920 2031 3220 2031 3520 2031  6   9  12  15  1
0000070: 3820 2032 3120 2032 3420 2032 3720 2033  8  21  24  27  3
0000080: 3020 2033 3320 2033 360a                 0  33  36.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this (output to a file) and I didn't find any extra white space in the resulting file

```
import sys

def mult_table(x,y):
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(1,y+1):
            for n in range(1,x+1):
                if n == 1:
                    print i*n,
                    print >> f,  i*n,
                elif n == x:
                    print repr(i*n).rjust(3)
                    print >> f, repr(i*n).rjust(3)
                else:
                    print repr(i*n).rjust(3),
                    print >> f, repr(i*n).rjust(3),

mult_table(12,3)
sys.exit(0)
```

There is a `0a` - newline after 36 but I consider that normal, is that considered a problem in your case?

Comment: Yes. I didn't think it was a problem at first, but now I am thinking that is why I am not getting credit for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the result in one environment and display it in another, it may cause problems.

```
0000000: 3120 2020 3220 2020 3320 2020 3420 2020  1   2   3   4
0000010: 3520 2020 3620 2020 3720 2020 3820 2020  5   6   7   8
0000020: 3920 2031 3020 2031 3120 2031 320D 0A32  9  10  11  12..2
0000030: 2020 2034 2020 2036 2020 2038 2020 3130     4   6   8  10
0000040: 2020 3132 2020 3134 2020 3136 2020 3138    12  14  16  18
0000050: 2020 3230 2020 3232 2020 3234 0D0A 3320    20  22  24..3
0000060: 2020 3620 2020 3920 2031 3220 2031 3520    6   9  12  15
0000070: 2031 3820 2032 3120 2032 3420 2032 3720   18  21  24  27
0000080: 2033 3020 2033 3320 2033 360D 0A          30  33  36..
```

There is 0D0A (CRLF) there in the output in my Windows 7 system running your code using standard output to a file. Maybe this is interpreted as white space in your case?

You may need to clarify how your code runes and how does it output the result, also in which format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I like my previous answer because it found a case where your program emits an empty space.

However, I checked out the problem on CodeEval and found that the challenge requires you to print out the table for **12x12** - not 12x3.

The challenge description only gives you *the first three lines* of the correct output.

Now when you examine CodeEval's report of what your program output is, yes, there is an extra space. (I tried it). But that is a CodeEval bug, not yours. Your program didn't emit that.

Red herring soup anyone?

*Take-home:* Read the question carefully. :-)